# Aggregate numeric values from jsonb array of records (including NULL values)

Tags: postgresql, casting, aggregate, jsonb

I'm using postgres 9.5 and my data is integers like this :

```
id | v1 | v2 | v3
---+----+----+------
 1 | 10 | 3  | null     
 2 | 5  |null| 1
 3 |null| 2  | 7
```

I have created a `jsonb` array like this:

```
 [{"v1": 10, "v2": 3, "v3": null}]
```

I'd like to run comparisons and Aggregations (IE sum all v1).

1) is **jsonb_array_elements** the correct operation or is there an easier way?

2) if **jsonb_array_elements** is best way, how do I cast to integer and generate **null** value so I can run comparisons/aggs?

See [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=dea188c1242f3dccc497d0939fb15339)

I've looked at several stack questions and this is as far as I have gotten:

```
SELECT id, x->'v1' AS v1
FROM   base,jsonb_array_elements(j) t(x);
```

Comment: You forgot to declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: edited, thanks again.  You're answers are always so spot on.  If you ever make an on line course on postgres, I'd be the first to signup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
SELECT sum((x->>'v1')::int) AS v1_sum
FROM   base, jsonb_array_elements(j) t(x);
```

Use the [**`->>`** operator instead of `->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) to get `text` values; then cast. Casting a `jsonb` NULL to `integer` fails, and you want `text` to begin with.

If you have more value columns, the [`-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) might also become attractive:  form a `jsonb` record from the whole row and subtract (delete) the `id` key:

```
SELECT id, json_agg(j1) AS j
FROM  (SELECT id, to_jsonb(t) - 'id' AS j1 FROM t) t1
GROUP  BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5a0e368320a0c2581eda7ca94a742409)*